# How to pass data from activity to class

Tags: android, class, android-activity, pass-data

Here is my activity code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_engineer_recycler );
    String value = "hello";
    }
```

Here is my class file :

```
public class complaintAdapter{
 //code here
}
```

Now can anyone help me how pass that "hello" from activity to class

Comment: Put value in Global variable and access it anywhere and in your class also.

Comment: add a setter to your class, and call it

Comment: my activitiy and class are two different file @ZubariaAshraf

Comment: that does not matter. You can make String variable static in your class and then sets its value from activity. @NikhilLohar

Comment: @ZubariaAshraf: Using static unnecessarily is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor in your ComplaintAdapter class

```
public class ComplaintAdapter{
 private String value;

 public ComplaintAdapter(String value){
    this.value = value;
 }
}
```

Then when you create the object of this class pass the value to constructor

```
ComplaintAdapter adapter = new ComplaintAdapter(value);
```

Comment: In ComplaintAdapter Class how to access the value outside this subclass

Comment: the value is available in value variable you can access it wherever you want in this class

Comment: If my answer helped you then please upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

There could be two solutions to this.

**Solution 1**

Using data from Activity during object creation like this.

Create a constructor in the class that could take the desired data like this

```
public class complaintAdapter{
private String _value;
    public complaintAdapter(String value){
        _value = value;
        // use _value
    }
}
```

This can be used in the activity like this.

Create a method in the class and call it using the data as a parameter.

```
String value = "hello";
complaintAdapter complaintAdapterObj = new complaintAdapter(value);
```

**Solution 2**

Using data from the activity in the method call like this.

Create a method in the class and call it using the data as a parameter.

```
public class complaintAdapter{
    private String _value;
    public void sendData(String value){
        _value = value;
        // use _value
    }
}
```

This can be used in the activity like this

```
String value = "hello";
complaintAdapter complaintAdapterObj = new complaintAdapter();
complaintAdapterObj.sendData(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_engineer_recycler );
    String value = "hello";
    ComplaintAdapter adapter = new ComplaintAdapter(value);

    //access to value
    adapter.getValue();  
}
```

and change Class in this way:

```
public class ComplaintAdapter{
     private String value;

     public ComplaintAdapter(String value){
        this.value = value;
     }

     public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
     }
}
```

Comment: In ComplaintAdapter Class how to access the value outside this subclass

Comment: You have reference in onCreate method called adapter. you can add setter and getter method to ComplaintAdapter, then use them like adapter.getValue() which returns the value

Answer (score 0):

To pass any value to class you should create an appropriate constructor. In this case you should do like this:

```
public class complaintAdapter {

  private String value;

  public complaintAdapter(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Then you create an instance in your activity:

```
complaintAdapter adapter = new complaintAdapter(value);
```

P.S. As Java Code conventions rule says - any java class name should start with uppercase symbol so you better rename your class to ComplaintAdapter

Comment: In ComplaintAdapter Class how to access the value outside this subclass